# Replace symbol in string with jq

Tags: jq

I have some problems transforming a string like this `"'mysql'"` to `"mysql"`. For this specific case, I was able to use `sub`:

`sub("'\'mysql\''";"mysql")`

But I need a more universal jq rule to remove single-quotes, e.g. `"'mystring'"` => `"mystring"`

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: I need to get "mysql" from "'mysql'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a named capture:

```sh
$ echo "[\"'mysql'\", \"'whatever'\"]" \
| jq '.[] | sub("'\''(?<s>[^'\'']+)'\''"; .s)'
"mysql"
"whatever"
```

Explanation:

- `'\''`  a single quote (escaped for the shell)
- `(?<s>` start of a capture group named `s`
- `[^'\'']+` one or more characters other than `'` (escaped for the shell)
- `)` end of the capture group
- `'\''` a single quote (escaped again for the shell)

Comment: I gave only a part of json, I need a more universal rule. Instead of "'mysql" "anything can be

Comment: To summarize, I need to delete ' ' for any string

Comment: @mifogon: Updated.

Comment: write it just for string, not array pls

Comment: @mifogon For a single string, just remove `.[] |`.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: can you help with this expression ? I need to use ```sub("'\''(?<s>[^'\'']+)'\''"; (.s))``` in Golang. It need ""?

Comment: I have no idea what regex syntax Golang uses, sorry.